# Apache mod_rewrite - unknown flag 'AND'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These rules are not working on apache 2.2.34

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC,AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/page\.php$ - [R=404,L]
```

I get `RewriteCond: unknown flag 'AND'`

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Indeed, such flag does not exist. The documentation does not contain such a flag.

Comment: Multiple RewriteCond are automatically joined with an _implicit_ AND, and the OR flag exists to allow you to change that. But an AND flag does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is not required (and not a valid flag either) as conditions are automatically ANDed together.

just use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

Moreover `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ [NC]` is not really doing anything and it matches `QUERY_STRING` with anything (including empty string).

Your final rul should be just this:

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?page\.php$ - [R=404,NC,L]
```